# Silverlight displaying asia language?

Tags: c#, silverlight

My application require 2 different asia language support: Chinese and Tamil.
It should be able to cater for change without compiling, something like java's resource bundle.
In this case, if I input unicode on a external file and get silverlight to read as string, will silverlight be able to parse it correctly?

Or I can use the chinese/ tamil characters directly in the external file, but I'm not sure how to retrieve these characters in code.

Anyway these language will be shown on the same screen, so I don't think localization will help.

Comment: These "files" are resource files containing localised versions of strings used in your UI?

Comment: By what means do you expect to retrieve the "external" file?

Comment: actually I have no problem hardcoding other aspect of the UI. Just that at a certain screen I will need to show different languages. I might have problem translating, so I thought for these languages I put them in an external file. So when I'm at my client's place, anything can just change

Comment: @anthony external file can be retrieved by webclient (xml), which I have been doing for my config. Mayb I just add in these 2 sentence in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the content in Xml (probably Xaml Resource dictionary) using the default UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Does it mean that I just directly input like "汉语" into xml then store it into Encoding?

Comment: @C_Rance: "Encoding" refers to how language characters are mapped to the numerical values stored in a file. When you save a file it will use an "Encoding". When saving an Xml or Xaml file in Visual Studio it defaults to using the UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8 can represent all the characters in the Unicode character set including chinese and tamil characters. So yes can just type them in directly.

Comment: the Encoding I meant was C#'s Encoding data type. Anyway I got u, thanks.